# Is it possible to use Yield keyword to return values without a loop?

Tags: c#, .net, keyword

I don't have a `for` loop and I want to return 5 integers from a method. Is this possible? Could you show me an example?

I want to return values one after another. I searched many examples but they all show the way to return `yield` value using a `for` loop, and some explanations say that it is not possible to use the `yield` keyword without a loop.

Comment: All 5 at once? Or one after the other?

Comment: -1. You have not researched anything and your needs are explained poorly. Improve question (e.g., add more context, real-world example(s), etc.), please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible , You can use yield keyword to return multiple values without using a for loop ,
And here is a nice example below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
public static class CodeExamples
{
  public static IEnumerable<int> YieldExampleWithoutLoop()
  {
    yield return 0;
    yield return 1;
    yield return 2;
    yield return 3;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes, absolutely:

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetValues()
{
    yield return 10;
    yield return 5;
    yield return 15;
    yield return 23;
    yield return 1;
}
```

You can have other code between the `yield return` statements, too. Although there are *some* restrictions about the code within iterator blocks, you can *mostly* use the normal code constructs - loops, conditions etc.

On the other hand, if you don't *need* any other code, why not just return a list or array (or something similar)?

```
public IEnumerable<int> GetValues()
{
    return new int[] { 10, 5, 15, 23, 1 };
}
```

If you have more specific requirements, please give us more details.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly fine:

```
IEnumerable<int> myFunc()
{
    yield return 1;
    yield return 1;
    yield return 1;
    yield return 1;
    yield return 42;
}
```

e: Beat me to it... to add insult to injury, I noticed that my code only returned four integers. BRB, getting coffee.